# When do we have $H(f(X)) = 0$?

Tags: information-theory, entropy

I am working on the following exercise:

> Let $X$ be a discrete RV with values in $\mathbb{R}$ and let $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be an
>   arbitrary measurable function.
>
> (a) Show that, in general, $H(f(X)) \le H(X)$.
>
> (b) When do we have equality $H(f(X)) = H(X)$?
>
> (c) When do we have $H(f(X)) = 0$?

I have done the points a) and b), but I do not understand what I am supposed to do in c). Could you explain?

Comment: Well the only way to make a positive sum be $0$ is if all of the terms are zero, but so Probabilities are positive and information is $0$ if $\log$ is $0,$ that happens when probabilities are $1,$ no longer very random.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of giving a complete answer, let me illustrate with an example.  Suppose the random variable $X$ takes two values $a$ and $b$ with probabilities $p$ and $q$.  Then
$$ H(X) = - p\log p - q \log q .$$
Now if $f(a) \ne f(b)$ then $H(f(X)) = H(X)$.  But if $f(a) = f(b)$ then $f(X)$ becomes a random variable taking only one value, and
$$ H(f(X)) = - (p+q)\log (p+q) .$$
In this particular case, $H(f(X)) = 0$ because $p+q = 1$.  But I wrote it this way so that you can see how to generalize.